# The right XQuery for inserting XML Attributes in XML variable in SQL Server based on if statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have the following xml:

```
               <tr>
            <td>Lycamobile</td>
            <td>EV</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>13951</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>332</td>
            <td>13951</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>332</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lycamobile</td>
            <td>EV</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>6494</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>6494</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lycamobile</td>
            <td>EV</td>
            <td>15.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7709</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7709</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lycamobile</td>
            <td>EV</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>8823</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8823</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>ATC</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>10641</td>
            <td>182</td>
            <td>58</td>
            <td>10641</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>58</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>ATC</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>6312</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>526</td>
            <td>6312</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>526</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>ATC</td>
            <td>15.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7674</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7674</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>ATC</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8873</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8873</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vodafone</td>
            <td>EV</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9911</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9911</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
```

I want to add a Attribute to every tr where the 12th td subelement is 58.

This would be the 5th tr in this example

The whole XML artifact is saved in variable @changesxml

I come so far:

```
SET @changesxml.modify('insert
    if (//tr/td[12]/text()="58")
    then attribute style {"background-color: #FF8B6F;"}
    else ()
        as first into   (/root/tr)[1] ')
```

But this adds it all the time to the first tr.

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds it all the time to the first tr because of

```
(/root/tr)[1]
```

You're telling it to add it to the first tr element found under the root element.

Something like this will do it for the first tr found that has a 12th td with a value of 58:

```
SET @xml.modify('insert     
attribute style {"background-color: #FF8B6F;"} 
into   (//tr[(td[12])/text()="58"])[1] ')
```

It'll only work for the first one found, but that should get you started.  You'll need to create a loop to get all of them.  If you create the loop and have the final indexer be dynamic then you will need to wrap everything into an sp_executesql and run it as a single command.  If you try to do something like:

```
SET @xml.modify('insert     
    attribute style {"background-color: #FF8B6F;"} 
    into   (//tr[(td[12])/text()="58"])[' + @val + '] ')
```

it will fail because .modify requires a string literal.  So you'll need to do something like

```
declare @command nvarchar(1000)
declare @int int = 1

SET @command = '
SET @xml.modify(''insert     
attribute style {"background-color: #FF8B6F;"} 
into   (//tr[(td[12])/text()="58"])[' + CAST(@int AS nvarchar(6)) + '] '') '

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @command,
                   @params = N'@xml xml out',
                   @xml = @xml OUTPUT

SELECT @xml
```

Where the variable @int is your counter variable.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i expected this answer. I hoped there exist a more elegant way.